# Placeholder for meta tags in the head

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, managed-metadata, custom-masterpage

Is there a placeholder that I can use in my custom page layout, that will allow me to load a `<meta>` viewport tag in the head of my master template?

I'm using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your custom master page has the same ContentPlaceHolders as the default one then you can use `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` this is where a lot of the standard SharePoint pages add meta tags

Comment: Thank you I just figured it out before you posted the answer, and stack exchange does not allow new users to answer their own questions.  But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a very similar issue to add meta tags to the header of our pages dynamically.  If your tag is static you can simply add it to the header section of the master page.  If the value is dynamic, take a look at the link below for a good way to dynamically add meta tags to the header of every page.

http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/